# React-Native top: -Number is leaving a white space at the bottom

Tags: react-native

In my app I'm trying to display a header with a container view below it. But when I use `top: -5` for example it leaves a whitespace in the bottom. How do I fix this ?

styling:

```
// all content
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    marginTop: isIphoneX() ? hp(3) : hp(0),
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  
  
  header: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  
  // orange container
  container: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
    borderTopLeftRadius: wp(7),
    borderTopRightRadius: wp(7),
    top: wp(-5),
    height: hp(65),
  },
```

Here is an image:
[image]

Comment: Give flex:1 to the parent and the search component

Comment: didn't work @decoder